# Is there a quick way to iterate through a JSON object, changing the title of each object to a value of one of it's key values?

Tags: javascript, json

For example, if I had a JSON object like so:

```
{
  "28595": {
    "displayProperties": {
      "description": "I wish to be strategic.",
      "name": "Helm of the Great Hunt",
      "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/c9ff2846a1474f315305e4f9bc413b2e.jpg",
      "hasIcon": true
    },
    "scope": 1,
    "sourceString": "Source: Last Wish raid.",
    "sourceHash": 2455011338,
    "itemHash": 2274520361,
    "acquisitionInfo": {
      "runOnlyAcquisitionRewardSite": false
    },
    "stateInfo": {
      "requirements": {
        "entitlementUnavailableMessage": "Requires Destiny 2: Forsaken"
      }
    },
    "presentationInfo": {
      "presentationNodeType": 2,
      "parentPresentationNodeHashes": [
        1847361717,
        558738844
      ],
      "displayStyle": 3
    },
    "hash": 28595,
    "index": 686,
    "redacted": false,
    "blacklisted": false
  },
  "637236": {
    "displayProperties": {
      "description": "I wish to be wise.",
      "name": "Hood of the Great Hunt",
      "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/b70e19e236a3cfd0fc762be6f2d226d9.jpg",
      "hasIcon": true
    },
    "scope": 1,
    "sourceString": "Source: Last Wish raid.",
    "sourceHash": 2455011338,
    "itemHash": 3251351304,
    "acquisitionInfo": {
      "runOnlyAcquisitionRewardSite": false
    },
    "stateInfo": {
      "requirements": {
        "entitlementUnavailableMessage": "Requires Destiny 2: Forsaken"
      }
    },
    "presentationInfo": {
      "presentationNodeType": 2,
      "parentPresentationNodeHashes": [
        1375933816,
        282080253
      ],
      "displayStyle": 3
    },
    "hash": 637236,
    "index": 1202,
    "redacted": false,
    "blacklisted": false
  }
}
```

Is there a quick way for me to iterate through each object (`28595` & `637236`) and replace the object title with the value of say `itemHash`?

So my first objects title would change to `2274520361` and my second would change to `3251351304`.

It would have to loop through the entire file as it is around 112,000 lines long, hence I would need a script that loops through the data but I don't know how to create one.

The reason for wanting to do this is because I am using item hashes in my application to reference each object but this JSON data doesn't use the standard item hashes like my other data used in the app does.

EDIT:

Preferably I'd like this done in JavaScript as I'm writing a React application but the file is stored locally and referenced via a `const` so if there was a way to do it using another language for me to then just use the updated file I'd be all ears and willing to give it ago

Comment: You should specify what programming languages or technologies you're looking to do this in.

Comment: I've updated my question, thanks for the tip

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant to let others do the programming for you. You should first try to develop the script and if you can't get it right, you can ask what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple for loop can be used to create a new object. Check for duplicate itemHash values is recommended just in case. Also, better to use new object instead of mutating the original one, to avoid some edge case issues.

```js
var result = {}, obj = {"28595":{"displayProperties":{"description":"I wish to be strategic.","name":"Helm of the Great Hunt","icon":"/common/destiny2_content/icons/c9ff2846a1474f315305e4f9bc413b2e.jpg","hasIcon":true},"scope":1,"sourceString":"Source: Last Wish raid.","sourceHash":2455011338,"itemHash":2274520361,"acquisitionInfo":{"runOnlyAcquisitionRewardSite":false},"stateInfo":{"requirements":{"entitlementUnavailableMessage":"Requires Destiny 2: Forsaken"}},"presentationInfo":{"presentationNodeType":2,"parentPresentationNodeHashes":[1847361717,558738844],"displayStyle":3},"hash":28595,"index":686,"redacted":false,"blacklisted":false},"637236":{"displayProperties":{"description":"I wish to be wise.","name":"Hood of the Great Hunt","icon":"/common/destiny2_content/icons/b70e19e236a3cfd0fc762be6f2d226d9.jpg","hasIcon":true},"scope":1,"sourceString":"Source: Last Wish raid.","sourceHash":2455011338,"itemHash":3251351304,"acquisitionInfo":{"runOnlyAcquisitionRewardSite":false},"stateInfo":{"requirements":{"entitlementUnavailableMessage":"Requires Destiny 2: Forsaken"}},"presentationInfo":{"presentationNodeType":2,"parentPresentationNodeHashes":[1375933816,282080253],"displayStyle":3},"hash":637236,"index":1202,"redacted":false,"blacklisted":false}}

for (var key in obj)
  if (obj[key].itemHash in result)
    console.log('duplicate itemHash value:', obj[key].itemHash)
  else
    result[obj[key].itemHash] = obj[key]
  
console.log( result )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that a is your JSON. Remember that a has to be let or var.

```
for (const key in a) {
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    a[a[key]["itemHash"]] = a[key];
    delete a[key];
  }
}
```